# Binding method of one class to eventListener of other class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, three.js

When I try to pass `this.someFunction` to `someClass.addEventListener()` (other class than this) I get following error

`TypeError: undefined has no properties`
when the event is executed. So it seems like reference to `this.someFunction` is valid only locally, but does not work from context of other class?

code is like this (deleted irelevant parts):

```js
class ThreeJS {

  constructor(container) {
    this.renderer = this.initRenderer(container);
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, this.renderer.aspectRatio, 1, 2000);
    this.controls = this.initControls(this.camera);
  }

  initRenderer(container) {
    let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true
    });
    return renderer;
  }

  initControls(camera) {
    let controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
    console.log(this.renderer); // Here this.renderer is defined
    controls.addEventListener('change', this.render);
    return controls;
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.renderer); // Here this.renderer is undefined
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }

}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  threeJS.controls.update();
}

// main()
var threeJS = new ThreeJS(document.getElementById("GLScreen"));
animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/93/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: I transferred your code into a snippet. As written, it does not throw any errors. That said, I also didn't see it firing TrackballControls `change` events.

Comment: If a class method is used by some other class, isn't better to create a global function, or else create a class with the shared method and extend it?

Comment: Also, i think you can call a class method of its instance, not the generic class.

Comment: Do `console.log(this)` instead of `console.log(this.renderer)` to find out why.